# Como esperar hasta que una imagen se encuentre disponible en Amazon S3 con NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, aws, amazon-s3

Feliz día a todos. Me encuentro con una duda. Estoy haciendo una app que publica imágenes en un bucket de S3, gracias a un servidor de NodeJS. El problema es que al subir las imágenes no son accesibles de inmediato, por lo tanto me gustaría conseguir la forma de poder esperar a que un objeto este disponible en el bucket de S3 para luego seguir con el código. Agradecería cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme. ¿Alguno tiene un trozo de código que pueda hacer esto?

Comment: No entiendo cuando decis que no es accesible de inmediato. Cuando trabajo con S3 cada archivo que envie ya tiene su acceso de inmedita.

Comment: Cuando me refiero a que no se ven de inmediato me refiero a que tarda algunos segundos (de 1 a 7 segundos aproximadamente en estar disponible). Entonces al cargar las imágenes y usarlas en un view html de inmediato, genera que la imagen no se observe y que el usuario tenga que dar reload a la página para intentar recargarla.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea una buena solución contar con alguna pieza de código que continuamente esté consultando si el objeto terminó o no de crearse. Lo que tal vez si podría ayudarte es configurar notificaciones a nivel del S3, de tal forma que una vez que un nuevo objeto haya terminado de crearse en el S3, este le notifique a un lambda y desde este lambda ya puedes hacer la implementación correspondiente para notificar al cliente que la imagen está cargada y lista para usarse.

Link de referencia para el setup de las notificaciones con S3:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html